# STP traffic generation [Malformed Packet] with scapy & wireshark

Tags: wireshark, scapy

I am trying to generate an STP packet and to capture it with wireshark, this is my code:

```
from scapy.all import STP
import scapy
from scapy.all import *

sendp(Dot3(dst="01:00:0c:cc:cc:cd", src="08:17:35:51:29:2e")/LLC(dsap=0xaa, ssap=0xaa)/SNAP(OUI=0x0c, code=0x010b)/STP(), iface="eth1", count=200)
```

I have been able to generate the desired output but I got an error in `wireshark`
[image]
Are there some fields that I should add in the `sendp` command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure STP protocol via scapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62899419/configure-stp-protocol-via-scapy)

Comment: not really, in wireshark, Spanning TRee Protocol is still in red

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran a few things, to see why.

1. is it not a problem of padding. I try to pad the packet to 60B as mandatory in network. (your wiresahrd says captured 57B so it is under). It has never been a problem for me, but I had to check.
2. I open an exemple capture from wireshark.
   https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=stp.pcap
   I opened the 1st packet using wireshar (and it was happy), then opened it using scapy:

   from scapy.utils import rdpcap

   packets = rdpcap("/home/fgagnaire/Downloads/stp.pcap")
   packets[0].show()

the output:

```
###[ 802.3 ]### 
  dst       = 01:80:c2:00:00:00
  src       = 00:1c:0e:87:85:04
  len       = 38
###[ LLC ]### 
     dsap      = 0x42
     ssap      = 0x42
     ctrl      = 3
###[ Spanning Tree Protocol ]### 
        proto     = 0
        version   = 0
        bpdutype  = 0
        bpduflags = 0
        rootid    = 32868
        rootmac   = 00:1c:0e:87:78:00
        pathcost  = 4
        bridgeid  = 32868
        bridgemac = 00:1c:0e:87:85:00
        portid    = 32772
        age       = 1.0
        maxage    = 20.0
        hellotime = 2.0
        fwddelay  = 15.0
###[ Padding ]### 
           load      = '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

now it looks like they are `building` the without the layer SNAP.

3. try to build without the SNAP layer:

   `from scapy.layers.inet import SNAP`

   `from scapy.layers.l2 import LLC, STP, Dot3`

   `from scapy.packet import Padding`

   `from scapy.utils import wrpcap`

   `packets = []`

   `packet = Dot3(dst="01:00:0c:cc:cc:cd", src="08:17:35:51:29:2e") / LLC() / STP()`

   `wrpcap("/tmp/test_file.pcap", packets)`

This makes wireshark happy. It also helps me understand that you question is not about STP but PVSTP+.

if your question is about PVSTP+, then I don't think scapy supports it out of the box. you have to build the layer yourself.